# How to maintain binding when input button is clicked using webmethod in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webmethod

I am trying to update my angular model using a known working webmethod (.net).

- I get data back from my webmethod logged to the console successfully.
- It updates the input-box value as well.
- **But this doesn't update my angular model binding.**

What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
 <input class="btn-primary" />
 <input class="txtCalls" ng-model="TotalCalls"/>
```

Angular

```
$scope.TotalCalls;
```

CodeBehind

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string GetCallData()
    {
         String Calls = "34";
         return Calls;
    }
```

Ajax Call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.btn-primary').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "Stats.aspx/GetCallData",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('.txtCalls').text(response.d);
                        console.log(response.d);
                    },

                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                        console.log(response.d);
                    }
                });
             });
```

Comment: btw [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true] is missing closing parenthesis )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because this is an JQUERY/Ajax call not an angular call. You need to make the call from a angular-controller and use `$http.get` instead of `$.ajax`

your button `.btn-primary` should add an `ng-click="someMethod()"` instead of the `JQuery on('click')`. Like:

```
<input class="btn-primary" ng-click="someMethod() />
```

I would assume you already have a controller so in it you will need to implement `someMethod` like:

```
$scope.someMethod = function(){  $http.get(...) };
```

Additionally angular is an MVVM framework and as part of this pattern you update the Model(data) instead of the view `html>form>input` control the two way binding will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you change values from "outside" angular, you'll need a reference to your angular `scope` and then call `scope.$apply()`.

For example:

```
var el = $('.txtCalls').get(0);
angular.element(el).scope().$apply();
```

But usually it's better to use angular provided code/procedures if possible (like `$http.get`)

Comment: this is encouraging following a terrible practice

Answer (score 0):

Use the angularJS $http.post inside of an angularJS controller or service or directive, instead of $.ajax.

Comment: it is a GET call not POST btw also explained in y POST along ago

Comment: then just use $http.get !! All in the angular.js documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http